# Batch file to sort files and list missing

Tags: windows, batch-file, search, file-io, cmd

I am trying to write a batch file that would read rows/lines from a txt file containing a list. The batch file would then copy the documents that match, and produce a list of missing files.

So far, the code successfully copies the files that it matches, but it also fills the "Missing.txt" file will exact contents of the input list, rather than simply the missing files.

```
@echo off

::Requests name of list file to be used by batch file
echo Enter list file name and press enter
set /p var=
mkdir %userprofile%\Desktop\%var%\

set /A lis=1

::Logic to search for files based on contents of list inputted by user at start.
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%var%.txt) DO (
    call :processline %%i
    IF NOT EXIST %%i (echo %%i>>%userprofile%\Desktop\%var%\Missing.txt) 
) 

pause


::Function called processline
::Assigns a string/value to variable "line"
::Copies a file with name = "line" to the user's desktop
::Renames the file to include a number reference, based on original list being searched
::Increments number for next file to be searched,copies and renamed

:processline
echo line=%*
xcopy /s %*.* %userprofile%\Desktop\%var%
move /Y %userprofile%\Desktop\%var%\%*.pdf %userprofile%\Desktop\%var%\%lis%_%*.pdf
set /A lis=%lis%+1

:eof
```

I suspect my problem is within the "for" logic, although there might be a way to input missing file names within the processline function.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's command order: `:processline` subroutine moves something, maybe including `%%i` file. I'd use next code snippet:

```
IF EXIST "%%~i" (
    call :processline %%i
) ELSE (
    >>"%userprofile%\Desktop\%var%\Missing.txt" echo %%i
)
```